# html element on top of header but behind main section, tried to correct using z-index but did not work

Tags: html, css

so i have designed a nav element where on a mobile device, you click a button (the 3 menu bar hamburger) and the nav element slides in from the left. on the original index page it appears on top of the header which is what i want, i didnt even have to use z-index to achieve this. so i created a login page with a form element and two inputs. i havent optimised the form element for mobile but i was having a look and althoughthe nav appears above the header, it appears underneath or behind the form. i tried correcting this by setting the z-index to 0 and 1 respectively but it didnt correct it.

i have a header in an includes file... here

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/head.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">

    <title>Pratts of carlow </title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
        <h1> Pratts of Carlow </h1>

        <div id="menubar">
          <div class="bar">
          </div>
          <div id="dos" class="bar">
          </div>
          <div class="bar">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="logos">
          <img src="images/fiat.png" alt="fiat logo">
          <img src="images/fiatpro.png" alt="fiat pro logo">
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="slidenav">
      <a href="#" id="exit"> x </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SALES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PARTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

here is the corresponding css for the header

```
            /* ****************************************************************************/
        /* CSS RESET */
        /* ****************************************************************************/

        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
        a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
        del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
        small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
        b, u, i, center,
        dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, legend,
        table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
        article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
        figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
        menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
        time, mark, audio, video {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            font: inherit;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }
        /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
        article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
            display: block;
        }
        body {
            line-height: 1;
        }
        ol, ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        blockquote, q {
            quotes: none;
        }
        blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
        q:before, q:after {
            content: '';
            content: none;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        /******************************************************************************/
        /******************************************************************************/

        body {
          position: relative;
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        header {
          position: relative;
          display: flex;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: rgb(170,10,50);
          border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(180,20,60);
        }

        header h1 {
          position: relative;
          font-family: helvetica;
          font-size: 30px;
          width: 200px;
          padding: 10px;
          letter-spacing: 2px;
          color: white;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        #menubar {
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 20px;
          top: 34px;
          right: 25px;
        }

        .bar {
          position: relative;
          width: 40px;
          height: 5px;
          background-color: white;
          border-radius: 3px;
        }

        #menubar:hover > .bar {
          background-color: rgb(180,180,180);
        }

        #dos {
          margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
        }

        nav {
          position: absolute;
          left: -150px;
          top: 0px;
          height: 100%;
          width: 80%;
          max-width: 150px;
          text-align: center;
          background-color: white;
          border-right: 1px solid grey;
          transition: left .5s ease-out;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        #exit {
          position: reltive;
          float: right;
          color: grey;
        }

        ul {
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
          clear: both;
        }

        nav ul li {
          border-top: 1px solid grey;
          padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
        }

        nav ul li:hover {
          background-color: rgb(240,240,240);

        }

        nav a {
          text-decoration: none;
          font-family: helvetica;
          font-size: 10px;
          margin: 10px;
          color: grey;
        }

        #logos{
          display: none
        }

        /******************************************************************************/
        /******************************************************************************/

        @media screen and (min-width: 680px){
          #menubar {display: none;}
          #exit{display: none;}

          nav {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 550px;
            max-width: 1200px;
            height: 25px;
            border: none;
          }

          nav ul {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;
          }

          nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 4px;
          }

          nav ul li:hover {
            background-color: white;
          }

          nav ul li a:hover {
            color: rgb(100,100,100);
          }

          #logos {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            justify-content: space-around;;
            height: 76px;
            width: 200px;
          }

          #logos img {
            max-width: 76px;
          }
        }
```

the footer

```
    <footer>
        <blockquote>
          <h2>ADDRESS</h2> <br>
          Pratts of Carlow <br>
          Pollerton Road <br>
          Carlow <br>
          R93 FX20
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote>
          <h2>CONTACTS</h2><br>
          Sales: <a href="mailto:sales@prattsofcarlow.ie">sales@PrattsofCarlow</a><br>
          Service: <a href="mailto:service@prattsofcarlow.ie">Service@PrattsofCarlow.ie</a><br>
          Parts: <a href="mailto:parts@prattsofcarlow.ie">Parts@PrattsofCarlow.ie</a><br>
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote>
          <h2>OPENING HOURS</h2>
          9.00am-6.00pm Monday to Friday<br>
          10.00am-1.00pm saturday
        </blockquote>
    </footer>

    <script src="scripts/mm.js">
    </script>

    <script src="scripts/exit.js">
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

and the footer css

```
    footer {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgb(40,40,40);
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: helvetica;
    }

    footer h2 {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: rgb(200,200,200);
    }

    blockquote {
      color: rgb(200,200,200);
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    blockquote a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgb(230,100,90);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 680px){
      footer{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }
    }
```

now heres the html for the login page its just some includes and an echo to print out some html

```
    <?php

    include 'view/header.php';

    echo    "<main id='login'>
                <form action='access.php' method='post' id='form1'>
                  <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='email'>
                  <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password'>
                  <button type='submit' form='form1' value='submit'>Login</button>
                </form>
             </main>";

    include 'view/footer.php';

    ?>
```

and the corresponding css

```
    #login {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 400px;
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: grey;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    #login input {
      margin: 10px auto;
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      border: none;
      background-color: grey;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      color: white;
    }

    #login input::placeholder {
      color: white;
    }

    #login input:focus {
      outline: none;
      background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
    }

    #login button {
      margin: 10px auto;
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: rgb(230,100,90);
    }
```

so what do i have to fix to get the nav to behave and go above any other elements?

Comment: where is the css for the nav menu?

Comment: its in the header css.

Comment: i just noticed its doing the same with the footer so presumably any other element will appear above it exluding the header. can anyone provide a fix for this its wrecking my head

Comment: i just noticed its doing the same with the footer so presumably any other element will appear above it luding the header. can anyone provide a fix for this its wrecking my head

Comment: normally i'd recommend using absolute positioning, but your code might not take well without further modifications

Comment: we can ignore the login page because the footer is doing the same as the main. so, the nav element is positioned absolutely (i tried fixed but still same results) so it shows at the top of the page. the header is positioned latively and that works fine, nav is on top of it. the footer is positioned relative but that doesnt work. what am i missing here? what changes would you propose?

Comment: nav menu positioned fixed so it overlaps the other content. header,body,footer sections position relative so they wrap after eachother

Comment: ill try that. although i think the problem was that the head and footer css were in different files

Comment: so i compiled both the head.css and foot.css into the one css file, the nav is appearing above both but there is a new problem. none of the footer styles are working

Comment: how are the files included?

Comment: i just checked the console. its not recieving footer styles, its like the document is not saving to include the footer rules but ive saved it several times now. ill go over it tomorrow for now its bed time. thanks for all your help

Comment: might be caching

Comment: created a new file, copied in all the css now its working fine. thanks again